# How to do a line break in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, line-breaks

this is my first question on stackoverflow.
I'm trying to do problem sets on OCW online classes in Python, and I don't know how to debug my code. I work with IDLE, and Python 2.7.

Here is my code:

```
balance = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annual_itst = float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
min_paymt_rate = float(raw_input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))

remaining_balance = balance

for i in range(1,13):
    min_monthly_paymt=min_paymt_rate*remaining_balance
    inst_paid = (annual_itst / 12.0 )*remaining_balance
    pcpl_paid = min_monthly_pamt - inst_paid
    remaining_balance -= pcpl_paid

print("Month: " & i, \n "Minimum monthly payment: " & "$" & round(min_monthly_paymt, 2), \n "Principle paid: " & "$" & round(pcpl_paid, 2),
      \n "Remaining balance: " & "$" & round(remaining_balance, 2))
```

When I execute it, I have a message error "unexpected character after line continuation character" with a red highlight just after the first line in the `print` function. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can either: 1. use multiple `print`s, where each appears on a separate line; or 2. put the `\n` **inside the string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is,
learn about operators and formatting to print output

```
balance = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annual_itst = float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
min_paymt_rate = float(raw_input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))

remaining_balance = balance

for i in range(1,13):
    min_monthly_paymt=min_paymt_rate*remaining_balance
    inst_paid = (annual_itst / 12.0 )*remaining_balance
    pcpl_paid = min_monthly_paymt - inst_paid
    remaining_balance -= pcpl_paid
print "\n\n\n"
print "Month: {}".format(i), '\n',"Minimum monthly payment: $ {}".format(round(min_monthly_paymt, 2)), '\n',"Principle paid:$ ".format(round(pcpl_paid, 2)),'\n',"Remaining balance: $".format(round(remaining_balance, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

To print out a newline, use a string containing a newline: `"\n"`.

To print out a complex string like you want, you can use multiple `print` statements (which normally add their own newlines), or assemble your string and then print it.

```
print("Month:", i)
print("Minimum monthly payment: $" + round(min_monthly_paymt, 2))
(etc.)
```

You can add together strings into a longer string, but not strings and ints. For that, you need to convert numbers to strings or learn about formatting statements.

Number to string:

```
print "Month: "+str(i)
```

String formatting:

```
report = """Month: %d
Minimum monthly payment: $%.2f
Principal paid: $%.2f
Remaining balance: %.2f"""

print report % (i, min_monthly_paymt, pcpl_paid, remaining_balance)
```

Read up on all of these methods; they are useful in different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert int to string for concatenation and you can print each line separately to print in different lines.

```
balance = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annual_itst = float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
min_paymt_rate = float(raw_input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))

remaining_balance = balance

for i in range(1,13):
    min_monthly_paymt=min_paymt_rate*remaining_balance
    inst_paid = (annual_itst / 12.0 )*remaining_balance
    pcpl_paid = min_monthly_paymt - inst_paid
    remaining_balance -= pcpl_paid

    print("Month: " + str(i))
    print("Minimum monthly payment: $" +str(round(min_monthly_paymt, 2)))
    print("Principle paid: $" + str(round(pcpl_paid, 2)))
    print("Remaining balance: $" + str(round(remaining_balance, 2)))
```